# How can I make JsonResult return an array of arrays (without field names) rather than an array of objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, flot

I have an IEnumerable list of date/value pairs that I am returning as a Json list to flot. However, when I call JsonResult(), the result looks like this:

```
[{"Date":date1, "Value":value1}, {"Date":date2, "Value":value2}...]
```

Flot is expecting

```
[[date1, value1], [date2, value2]...]
```

Is there any simple way to get the MVC framework to output objects like this or do I need to write my own seralizer / StringBuffer code? For that matter I don't even need to output the field names, just the values themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to return a string like this:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("[");
foreach (var item in listOfDateTimes)
    builder.AppendFormat("[{0}, {1}], ", item.Key, item.Value);
var result = builder.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[]{',',' '}) + "]";
return result;
```

Comment: builder.AppendFormat in case anyone tries to copy/paste this code later :)

Comment: @jedidja Thanks for the catch, my air code is never perfect =P

Comment: Also for future reference, I ended up returning ContentResult from the method. Trying to return Json() of a string leaves it in quotes and flot is looking for an array.

    return Content(result, "json")

Answer (score 5):

Are these date/value pairs type of `System.Web.UI.Pair`? If so, you can do this ;

```
return Json(yourIEnumerable.Select(x => new[] { x.First, x.Second }).ToArray());
```

It returns the way you want it to be ;

```
[["\/Date(1255686550232)\/","foo"],["\/Date(1255686550232)\/","bar"]]
```

Even if they're not type of `System.Web.UI.Pair`, I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write it yourself, but it is a trivial exercise to do.

In my mind, is it worth spending on hour looking for a way to do it, when you can spend 10 minutes and just do the serialization yourself.

Comment: I figured that with so many Helpers in MVC there might be an option to  tweak somewhere :)